# 3Sum - leetcode

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, hash-map

**[Question](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/):**

> Given an integer array nums, return all the triplets [nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]] such that i != j, i != k, and j != k, and nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0.

Notice that the solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

Here's my pythonic approach to leetcode 3Sum, it passes and actually beats 93% in time!  However, the code is unweildy and the approach seems much overly complicated.  I am looking to clean up the two sum function, and overall approach, but I'm not sure how.

```py
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        def twoSum(i,target):
            ans = []
            for j in range(i+1,len(nums)):
                #avoid dupes
                if j > i+1 and nums[j] == nums[j-1]:
                    continue
                if nums[j] > target//2:
                    break
                # when target is even, two dupes may add to make it
                if nums[j] == target/2 and j+1 < len(nums):
                    if nums[j+1] == target // 2:
                        ans.append([nums[i],nums[j],nums[j+1]])
                        break
                #traditional two sum variation
                elif -(-target + nums[j]) in values and -(-target + nums[j]) != nums[j]:
                    ans.append([nums[i],nums[j],-(-target + nums[j])])
            return ans
        
        values = set(nums)
        nums.sort()
        answer = []
        for i,num in enumerate(nums):
            if i > 0 and nums[i-1] == nums[i]:
                continue
            values.remove(num)
            answer.extend(twoSum(i,-num))

        return answer
```

Even if you aren't able to follow my code, I would really appreciate general pythonic tips.  Thanks!

Comment: Providing the problem statement and/or sample in- and output will help contributors point you towards a better or more straightforward solution. As it is now, it's hard to understand what's (supposed to be) going on.

Comment: It doesn't address Python-specific questions, but the Wikipedia [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM#Quadratic_algorithm) for 3sum is intuitive and has a nice visualization to accompany it. Seems like a simpler algorithmic approach than the one you've taken, so it might be worth a look.